# undeclared object but everything implemented

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, three20, restkit

i implemented first three20 (first, with the python scrip) and then restkit (second,manual).
i started adding some stuff to my app delegate, but then i get an error `[RKObjectLoaderTTModel undeclared`. Other Objects `RKClient` or `RKObjectManager` work fine.

```
// work
[RKClient clientWithBaseURL:APP_BASE_URL username:USER_EMAIL password:USER_PASSWORD];
RKObjectManager* objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:APP_BASE_URL];
//fail
[RKObjectLoaderTTModel setDefaultRefreshRate:1];
```

looking into `RestKit/Build/RestKit/Three20` i can see `RKObjectLoaderTTModel` header.

i added all header search paths, etc , pp.

i think you get a better view, when looking into my project, sohere is it (have nothing done yet, so no problem with sharing): http://dl.dropbox.com/u/80699/project_for_stack.zip

hopefully somebody can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#import <RestKit/Three20/Three20.h>
```

had to import explicit the restkit three20 stuff.

hope this helps somebody. now everything runs fine.